# SQL Server CE with EF causing error while trying to do migration for datatimeoffset

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I am using `Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact version="4.0.8876.1"` along with `EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact version="6.2.0"`. While I try to create database `cfdb.sdf`, I am getting the error shown below. I am NOT using any `DateTimeOffset`. What could be the issue?

> An error has occurred.
>
> There is no store type corresponding to the EDM type 'Edm.DateTimeOffset(Nullable=False)' of primitive type 'DateTimeOffset'.","type":"System.NotSupportedException
>
> Stacktrace:
>
> at System.Data.Entity.SqlServerCompact.SqlCeProviderManifest.GetStoreType(TypeUsage edmType)
>   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.Services.StructuralTypeMappingGenerator.MapTableColumn(EdmProperty property, String columnName, Boolean isInstancePropertyOnDerivedType)
>   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.Services.PropertyMappingGenerator.Generate(EntityType entityType, IEnumerable`1 properties, EntitySetMapping entitySetMapping, MappingFragment entityTypeMappingFragment, IList`1  propertyPath, Boolean createNewColumn)
>   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.Services.TableMappingGenerator.Generate(EntityType entityType, DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping)
>   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.Services.DatabaseMappingGenerator.GenerateEntityTypes(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.Services.DatabaseMappingGenerator.Generate(EdmModel
>   conceptualModel)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbProviderManifest
>   providerManifest, DbProviderInfo providerInfo)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection
>   providerConnection)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext
>   internalContext)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)\r\n
>
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()\r\n
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type
>   entityType)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator()\r\n
>
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Web.OData.Formatter.Serialization.ODataResourceSetSerializer.WriteResourceSet(IEnumerable
>   enumerable, IEdmTypeReference resourceSetType, ODataWriter writer,
>   ODataSerializerContext writeContext)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.OData.Formatter.Serialization.ODataResourceSetSerializer.WriteObjectInline(Object
>   graph, IEdmTypeReference expectedType, ODataWriter writer,
>   ODataSerializerContext writeContext)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.OData.Formatter.Serialization.ODataResourceSetSerializer.WriteObject(Object
>   graph, Type type, ODataMessageWriter messageWriter,
>   ODataSerializerContext writeContext)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.OData.Formatter.ODataMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type
>   type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content,
>   HttpContentHeaders contentHeaders)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.OData.Formatter.ODataMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type
>   type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content,
>   TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location
>   where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Owin.HttpMessageHandlerAdapter.d__27.MoveNext()"}}}

Comment: You need to share more code - why is OData in the stack trace???

Comment: Thanks @ErikEJ, I am trying to use `odata` with `EF`. Is this supported with `sql-server-ce`